# How to change bulb in this bathroom light?

Tags: light-fixture

This bathroom light fixture with frosted dome and white surround was here when we moved in. The fluorescent bulb has now failed, but I can't get at the bulb. Does anyone know how to open this type of fixture?

I have turned it left and right, pulled, pushed, and pushed and turned as much as I am comfortable doing, but I don't want to overdo it.

There's a small gap between the surround and the ceiling. I have run my finger around it but did not feel any screws. There is one small gap in the base that could be for a side-entry cable.

Edit: This is in Ireland.

[image: Bathroom light fixture with frosted dome and white surround]

Comment: Is the white plastic surround slightly flexible, or does it seem brittle (which could be due to age)? You might be able to flex it a bit and take a photo with a mobile phone to see if it looks like the cover could be clipped on.

Comment: How new is it??

Comment: The surround is mildly flexible, but I tried taking photos days ago and couldn't get anything comprehensible.

Comment: I don't know how old the fixture is. Could be a couple of decades. The house is 70 years old, but it's definitely not the original bathroom light.

Comment: Reason I ask is that very modern fixtures are like transistor radios. A whole generation had to wrestle with the fact that *not only* didn't they have replaceable vacuum tubes, but the transistors are soldered down (because the sockets caused more problems than the transistors!)  Likewise, LED (as a light-making device) is so reliable that there is no reason to socket them either. So many fixtures are made socket-free.  However cheap makers often cut corners on the electronic drivers, and they fail.

Answer (score 4):

We have a couple of similar shaped lights and you have to rotate glass dome anticlockwise to "unlock" it and then gently lower it off the body of the light to expose the bulb and access the screws that hold the rest of it in place. It takes a firm grip because there's a seal touching the glass that resists spinning. Every time I think I'm going to break it. You have to push firmly up while twisting. Wearing rubber gloves might help get a better grip.

See [this other question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/179076/60082) for a photo of how the glass locks into place. I expect yours uses a similar system.

Comment: A suction cup or two might prove helpful.